# Why does Perl's Win32::ChangeNotify fire two events when a file changes?

Tags: windows, perl, winapi

I want to auto run `prove` when sources or tests are changed, I am using [Win32::ChangeNotify](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32%3a%3aChangeNotify), but I don't know why even a single file change, the `while` body runs two times, I actually want to monitor all changes, but only perform the action one time.

```
require Win32::ChangeNotify;

$notify = Win32::ChangeNotify->new("./", 1, "LAST_WRITE");

while (my @events = $notify->wait) {
    print @events, "----\n";
    $notify->reset;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File::ChangeNotify` gives better events and it's cross platform.

```
use File::ChangeNotify;
use Data::Dumper;

$| = 1;

my $watcher = File::ChangeNotify->instantiate_watcher(
    directories => [ 't', 'lib' ],
    filter => qr/\.t|\.pl|\.pm/,
);

while (my @events = $watcher->wait_for_events) {
    print Dumper(@events);
}
```

It prints single event when a single file is modified, at least that's what I observed.

Answer (score 4):

Raymond Chen discusses a similar topic in [Why does saving a file in Notepad fire multiple FindFirstChangeNotification events?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/05/07/10523172.aspx)

> Remember the original design goals of the [Read­Directory­ChangesW function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/08/12/10195186.aspx): It's for letting an application cache a directory listing and update it incrementally. Given these design goals, filtering out redundant notifications in the kernel is not required aside from the performance benefits of reduced chatter. In theory, Read­Directory­ChangesW could report a spurious change every 5 seconds, and the target audience for the function would still function correctly (albeit suboptimally).
>
> Given this intended usage pattern, any consumer of [Read­Directory­ChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) needs to accept that any notifications you receive encompass the minimum information you require in order to keep your cached directory information up to date, but it can contain extra information, too. **If you want to respond only to actual changes, you need to compare the new file attributes against the old ones.** (*emphasis mine*)

And, he clarifies even further below:

> The file system change notification does not check whether a write was equal to the previous data. (This gets really expensive for large file writes.) Remember the purpose of change notifications. **Spurious notifications are legal.** -Raymond (again, *emphasis mine*)

Comment: `$notify->wait` doesn't return any information on which file has been modified, it's not easy for me to compare the file attributes, neither do I care, I only want to call an external command when some files are updated. Maybe I can ignore consecutive events within an period, but I don't know if there's a better solution.

Comment: @Sawyer The better solution is to actually look at the last modified date for the files and see if any of them were actually updated.  If not, then you can ignore the notice as spurious.

Comment: @Sawyer I understand what is most convenient for you, but the point is there is nothing in the underlying OS API that will guarantee that a single notification will be fired for what you consider to be a single change. [Read­Directory­ChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives the changes.